# Need to Write Swagger yaml for SseEmitter rest (MVC server-sent-events )

Tags: java, yaml, swagger, server-sent-events

I'm writing swagger yaml for below rest, but not able to manage return type as SseEmitter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sse")
public SseEmitter getSseEmitter() {
    emitter = new SseEmitter();
    return emitter;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?? It is not clear what you did and what you want to do!

Answer (score 4):

I guess SSE is not supported by Swagger:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/396

but you can vote for it!

Comment: Five years later and there is still no conclusions on this - I personally am strongly considering dropping my SSE enabled endpoints from OAS spec - which is a real shame, but I prefer this than all the tooling to fail because SSE is not well supported  / standarized in OAS

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around using `text/event-stream` instead of `application/json`

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/396#issuecomment-1958240639

https://github.com/tazatechnology/openapi_spec/issues/34#issuecomment-1804385475